# Android Accessibility Service Start to Open a App window

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I am Making an Application in which I want to implement the feature that If user using any app, WhatsApp, Messenger etc. whenever he write '@' symbol the accessibility service got call and open a window with images to choose one to add in message anywhere he/she wants.

Maybe I am looking for something wrong, Please Guide me.
From Accessibility service i mean, when you install the application it will show in Setting->Accessibility and in service section it will show you your application with on/off functionality.

Please Help me with this, I'll be very thank full for any guide any something to direct me in right direction
Regards

Comment: have u implemented the service? if so, then you should be able to achieve above by using event.getText(), then you can check if text contains that special character, if it does start the activity.

Comment: there are some checks that if your service is installed correctly you can show your app name in Settings -> Accessibility in service section. I follow some tutorials but there is nothing in Accessibility section regarding my app so there are no sign even if service is working @k0sh

Comment: Why not develop your own keyboard?

Comment: ya...what you want to achieve, can be, using your own IME (keyboard). But then you'll have to develop all other features like swype, prediction, etc. Using accessibility service, you won't get the text content of window views 'While The User Is Typing'. When the user sends the message on button click, you will receive an event & then only can you get the text content.

Comment: Check out https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html#act-for-users . The best guide to develop something like this. If you still face any issues, contact me, I will add code.